# Нужна подсказка с действиями с словарями в Python

Tags: python

Я делаю кодировщик морзе, как мне сделать так, что бы когда я вводил текст, кодировщик сразу мне выводил символы морзе?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код вашего решения и напишите что с ним не так.

Comment: ну, вам для этого нужно сделать словарь. Вы делаете все правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете Windows, вы можете использовать модуль [msvcrt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html) . Я набросал примерный алгоритм:

```
import msvcrt
someMorze = {"a": "*--*", "b":"-*-", "c":"---*"}
result = ''
key = b''
while key != b'\r': # b'\r' это enter
    if msvcrt.kbhit(): # ожидание нажатия
        key = msvcrt.getch() # получение кнопки
        decodedKey = key.decode('ascii') # декод в str
        if decodedKey in someMorze:
            result += " " + someMorze[decodedKey] # выбор из списка
        print("\r"+ result, end="")
```